# Can we use the Softlayer "search" API to find a VM using its hostname?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Can we use the Softlayer "search" API to find a VM in my account using its hostname ? If so can we have a usage/example to use the same in Java ?

Many thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

This is a java example using [SoftLayer_Search::advancedSearch](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Search/advancedSearch):

```
import com.softlayer.api.ApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.RestApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.service.container.search.Result;
import com.softlayer.api.service.virtual.Guest;
import com.softlayer.api.service.Search;

public class GetVirtualGuestsUsingSearch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String username = "set me";
        String apikey = "set me";
        ApiClient client = new RestApiClient("https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/").withCredentials(username, apikey);


      for (Result item : Search.service(client).advancedSearch("fullyQualifiedDomainName:*myhostname* _objectType:SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest")) {
                Guest guest = (Guest) item.getResource();
                System.out.println("Server: " + guest.getFullyQualifiedDomainName());

        }

    }

}
```

And this is a **REST example** just in case:

URL:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Search/advancedSearch
```

Method: POST

Json Payload:

```
{
"parameters": [
"fullyQualifiedDomainName:*myhostname* _objectType:SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest"
]
}
```

Notice that `"SoftLayer_Search"`works using `"v3.1"`